# ThreeJS parsing buffergeometry from FBX to geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry, fbx

I wanted to parse a buffer geometry from an FBXloader to a geometry.

```
let myGeometry;
const loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();

loader.load( 'models/path_to_mesh.fbx',  ( object ) => {
  object.traverse(  ( child ) => {
      if ( child.isMesh && child.geometry.isBufferGeometry) {
         myGeometry = (new THREE.Geometry()).fromBufferGeometry(child);
      }
  } );
} );
```

Got an error :

> TypeError: THREE.Geometry is not a constructor

I tried to make a simple geometry and got the same error:

```
const geo = new THREE.Geometry();
```

I'm using Three.min 127dev

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`THREE.Geometry` has been removed from core since `r125`. It is still available as a ES6 module in the `examples` directory. At least with the current release `r126`. You can import it like so:

```js
import { Geometry } from 'three/examples/jsm/deprecated/Geometry.js';
```

However, it is recommended to not work with this class anymore since all other engine components (helpers, exporters, renderers etc.) have stopped support for it.